# ListCellRenderer - JLabel - String - n rows

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jlist, listcellrenderer

So I have this situation:

I have a JList that displays a bunch of Strings.

However, these strings are really long and JList is really narrow. Meaning the strings won't fit.

What I want to do is make each entry to have two rows, like this:

```
|Word word word  |
|word word wor...|
```

It would do wordWrap for the first row, and then finish the secon't row by cutting the rest of the string and appeinging the three dots to what is left in a way maximum space is filled.

It doesn't really matter what I do, the important thing is that I have to use FontMetrics to measure all this stuff so I can make it work. And that's the catch.

Until whole `getListCellRendererComponent(...)` method is executed, the component will not be painted, thus having no graphics, thus making any font measurement impossible.

How do I get around it?

P.S. I need to use the JLabel for the visuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the component will not be painted, thus having no graphics, thus making any font measurement impossible.

You don't need the Graphics to use the FontMetrics.

See [Left Dot Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/left-dot-renderer/) which is used for a JTable, but the concepts should be the same for a list renderer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You *need* to use JLabels? It'd be a lot easier to have getListCellRendererComponent() return a JTextArea whose height has been set to 2 lines and which has setLineWrap() and  setWrapStyleWord() both set to true. Make the JTextArea uneditable, and it'll look like a 2-line JLabel.